# calculate the frequency of two actors voting the same thing

Tags: r, frequency

I'm trying to calculate how often, on average, Germany agreed with the US on a vote in the UN general assembly since 1990. For this, I'm using the `unvotes` package (hosted both on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/unvotes/index.html) and [GitHub](https://github.com/dgrtwo/unvotes)) provides data on the voting history of countries in the [United Nations General Assembly]. I'm focusing on the un_votes and un_roll_calls datasets, which I merged.

So far I have this:

```
##count how often Germany and the US agreed on a resolution in each year:
countries <- c("United States", "Germany")

by_country_year <- merged %>%
  group_by(year = year(date), country, unres, rcid, vote) %>%
    filter(country %in% countries, year >= 1990)
```

but I am completely lost as to how I can go ahead. Any leads?

Comment: It would be useful if you included the code you used to create the data set `merged`

Comment: there you go: merged <- un_votes %>%
  inner_join(un_roll_calls, by = "rcid")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter according to dates and country, then group by rcid, before summarizing to create two separate columns for the US and German votes.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(unvotes)

merged <- un_votes %>% inner_join(un_roll_calls, by = "rcid") 

result <- merged %>% 
  filter(date >= as.Date('1990-01-01')) %>%
  filter(country %in% c('United States', 'Germany')) %>%
  group_by(rcid) %>%
  summarize(US_vote = vote[country == 'United States'],
            Germany_vote = vote[country == 'Germany'])
```

This now allows a table of all votes and how they compare between the two countries.

```r
table(US = result$US_vote, Germany = result$Germany_vote)
#>          Germany
#> US        yes abstain  no
#>   yes     629      15   4
#>   abstain 262      89   0
#>   no      719     399 423
```

We can also see whether the proportion of agreement is what we might expect by chance. Let's first drop the abstentions and then use a `prop.test`

```r
result <- result %>% filter(US_vote != 'abstain' & Germany_vote != 'abstain')

prop.test(sum(result$US_vote == result$Germany_vote), nrow(result))
#> 
#>  1-sample proportions test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  sum(result$US_vote == result$Germany_vote) out of nrow(result), null probability 0.5
#> X-squared = 60.611, df = 1, p-value = 6.955e-15
#> alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.5693588 0.6155882
#> sample estimates:
#>         p 
#> 0.5926761
```

This means that on votes where neither abstained, Germany and the US were more likely to vote the same way than would be expected by chance. I find this reassuring.

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could reshape your data.frame into a wide format using `pivot_wider()` and then count the number of times both columns (US and Germany) have the same value. Such as:

```
dt_wide = by_country_year %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = "rcid", names_from = country, values_from = "vote")
sum(dt_wide$Germany == dt_wide$`United States`, na.rm = T)
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
merged <- merge(un_votes, un_roll_calls, by = "rcid")
out <- xtabs(count ~ rcid + country + vote, 
  transform(subset(merged, 
     date >= as.Date("1990-01-01") & 
   country %in% c('United States', 'Germany')), count = 1))
```